# Activity don't work in 4.3 and 4.4.2

Tags: android, button, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

[image]

I have an activity with only some buttons. When I click in one appears an Alert Dialog.
It works in 2.3.6, 4.0.3 and 4.1.2, but in 4.3 and 4.4.2 I had a problem.

My errors:

```
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MYPROJECT/br.com.MYPROJECT.MYACTIVITY}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at br.com.MYPROJECT.MYACTIVITY.onCreate(Padroeiros.java:139)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
05-15 19:15:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(16247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

Comment: Please post the code in the file and then we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you all. I found my error, I was doing a reference to "R.id.buttonX" but in my xml I had "R.botao.buttonX"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at br.com.MYPROJECT.MYACTIVITY.onCreate(Padroeiros.java:139)
```

you have a Null Pointer Exception at line 139 of Padroeiros.java

Comment: 139 - buttonX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //some code }  Where´s the NullPointer? O.o

Comment: I don't know? use the debugger and step through to find out.

Comment: Your buttonX member is most probably null. Check in debug mode, whether you ever initialized it.

Comment: Button buttonX = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonX); It´s not null. I´ll check the debug mode carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
check  your  manifest
```

you  app  package  and your activity   package can  be  different.
but  in  this  case  please  use activity  full  path  in   name  attribute

for  example :

```
   <activity
            android:name="br.com.MYPROJECT.MYACTIVITY"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>
```